# Failed to call native dll

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke

```
Trying to use the command dll (c + +) project to c #
Structure dll
```

```
typedef struct {
SSP_FULL_KEY Key;
unsigned long BaudRate;
unsigned long Timeout;
unsigned char PortNumber;
unsigned char SSPAddress;
unsigned char RetryLevel;
unsigned char EncryptionStatus;
unsigned char CommandDataLength;
unsigned char CommandData [255];
unsigned char ResponseStatus;
unsigned char ResponseDataLength;
unsigned char ResponseData [255];
unsigned char IgnoreError;
} SSP_COMMAND;

typedef struct {
unsigned __int64 FixedKey;
unsigned __int64 EncryptKey;
} SSP_FULL_KEY;
```

Here is the code that I turned

```
public struct SSP_FULL_KEY
    {
        long FixedKey;
        long EncryptKey;
        public SSP_FULL_KEY (long fix, long encr)
        {
            FixedKey = fix;
            EncryptKey = encr;
        }

    }
    public struct SSP_COMMAND
    {
        / / String PortNumber;
        SSP_FULL_KEY key;
        long BaudRate; / / baud rate of the packet
        long Timeout; / / how long in ms to wait for a reply from the slave
        string PortNumber; / / the serial com port number of the host
        string SSPAddress; / / the SSP address of the slave
        string RetryLevel; / / how many retries to the slave for non-response
        string EncryptionStatus; / / is this an encrypted command 0 - No, 1 - Yes
        string CommandDataLength; / / Number of bytes in the command
        string [] CommandData; / / Array containing the command bytes
        string ResponseStatus; / / Response Status (PORT_STATUS enum)
        string ResponseDataLength; / / how many bytes in the response
        string [] ResponseData; / / an array of response data
        string IgnoreError; / / flag to suppress error box (0 - display, 1 - suppress)

        public SSP_COMMAND (string comport)
        {
            BaudRate = 9600;
            Timeout = 500;
            PortNumber = comport;
            RetryLevel = "5";
            IgnoreError = "0";
            EncryptionStatus = "0";
            CommandData = new string [255];
            ResponseData = new string [255];
            ResponseStatus = "0";
            ResponseDataLength = "0";
            SSPAddress = "0";
            CommandDataLength = "0";
            key = new SSP_FULL_KEY (0123456701234567, 0123456701234567);

        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        / / [DllImport ("ITLSSPProc.dll")]
        / / Private static extern int OpenSSPComPort (IntPtr smd);

        [DllImport ("ITLSSPProc.dll")]

        private static extern int OpenSSPComPort (SSP_COMMAND cmd);

        static void Main (string [] args)
        {
            SSP_COMMAND cmd = new SSP_COMMAND ("6");
            / * IntPtr.BaudRate = 9600;
            IntPtr.PortName = "COM0";
            IntPtr.Parity = Parity.None;
            IntPtr.StopBits = StopBits.One;

            * /
            Console.WriteLine (OpenSSPComPort (cmd));





        }
```

```
Comes out an error
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
UPDATE
Remade, still the same error
```

`public unsafe struct SSP_FULL_KEY
    {
        System.Int64 FixedKey;
        System.Int64 EncryptKey;
        public SSP_FULL_KEY(System.Int64 fix, System.Int64 encr)
        {
            FixedKey = fix;
            EncryptKey = encr;
        }

    }
    public unsafe struct SSP_COMMAND
    {
        //string PortNumber;
        SSP_FULL_KEY key;
        System.Int64 BaudRate; // baud rate of the packet
        System.Int64 Timeout; // how long in ms to wait for a reply from the slave
        string PortNumber; // the serial com port number of the host
        string SSPAddress; // the SSP address of the slave
        string RetryLevel; // how many retries to the slave for non-response
        string EncryptionStatus; // is this an encrypted command 0 - No, 1 - Yes
        string CommandDataLength; // Number of bytes in the command
        fixed char CommandData[255]; // Array containing the command bytes
        string ResponseStatus; // Response Status (PORT_STATUS enum)
        string ResponseDataLength; // how many bytes in the response
        fixed char ResponseData[255]; // an array of response data
        string IgnoreError; // flag to suppress error box (0 - display,1- suppress)

        public SSP_COMMAND(string comport)
        {
            BaudRate = 9600;
            Timeout = 500;
            PortNumber = comport;
            RetryLevel = "5";
            IgnoreError = "0";
            EncryptionStatus = "0";
            ResponseStatus = "0";
            ResponseDataLength = "0";
            SSPAddress = "0";
            CommandDataLength = "0";
            key = new SSP_FULL_KEY(0123456701234567, 0123456701234567);

        }
    }`

Comment: going to need a lot of MarshalAs on those strings

Answer (score 1):

You turned `__int64` correctly into C# `long`.

And then you want and also made `long BaudRate` and `long Timeout` into C# `long`, but that's wrong, these are 32-bit variables.

Best to forget that the type `long` ever existed (as far as interop is concerned) because it always adds confusion.  Just use `System.Int64` and `System.Int32` as appropriate.

Your strings are also wrong, they are inline char arrays in C++, which means you'll need to use attributes in the C# or else [a `fixed` array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx).

Comment: If you can describe a little more, or if possible example of a show that I did not understand you, I just called \ ovichek in this case

Comment: That is, if I understand you correctly my mistakes that I use logn instead must use System.Int64 \ (32) and deal with the array, and the rest right?

Comment: @ashenemy: Yes, you should use `System.Int64` (and `Int32`).  The problem with `long `is that it means 32 bits in MSVC++ and 64 bits in C#.  Fix that and the array and I think you should be good to go.